"{}" breaking the json_decode()
Update:

PanicException was fixed by pull/18249 in Polars 1.6.0
Broadcast length was fixed by pull/19148 in Polars 1.10.0

shape: (1, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ meta_data │
│ ---       │
│ struct[0] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {}        │
└───────────┘


I want to make the string of empty dictionary to be a struct, but json_decode fails as there are some rows with strings of empty dictionary in a df
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "meta_data": ["{}"]
})
df.with_columns(pl.col('meta_data').str.json_decode())

giving me,
PanicException: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ComputeError(ErrString("a StructArray must contain at least one field"))

edit -
the column has more string containing key value pairs also,
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': ['{}', '{"b": "c"}']})
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("a").str.json_decode())

the above one is working fine, but when I keep only '{}', then it breaks

I get a different error on 1.8.1: "ShapeError: unable to add a column of length 0 to a DataFrame of height 1"

At the moment Polars doesn't support structs without fields - see related issue. So it cannot work with only empty json objects.
However, if you know which fields can be in your data you can supply appropriate dtype parameter to pl.Expr.str.json_decode():
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": ["{}"]})

df.with_columns(
    pl.col('a').str.json_decode(dtype=pl.Struct({"b": pl.Utf8}))
)

shape: (1, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ a         │
│ ---       │
│ struct[1] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {null}    │
└───────────┘

Which would also work for rows with non-empty data:
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': ['{}', '{"b": "c"}']})

print(df.with_columns(
    pl.col('a').str.json_decode(dtype=pl.Struct({"b": pl.Utf8}))
))

shape: (2, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ a         │
│ ---       │
│ struct[1] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {null}    │
│ {"c"}     │
└───────────┘

If you don't know the data in advance then you cannot provide proper dtype parameter. In this case polars will try to determine schema based on data, using infer_schema_length parameter. By default it would check first 100 values to define schema.
If there's no meaningful values within the rows defined by infer_schema_length then your query might fail, and if the schema is not fully represented within these rows then the result might be incomplete:
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': ['{}', '{"b": "c"}', '{"e": "d"}']})

# we only check first 2 rows to determine schema
# so field e is not in the result
df.with_columns(
    pl.col('a').str.json_decode(infer_schema_length=2)
)

shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ a         │
│ ---       │
│ struct[1] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {null}    │
│ {"c"}     │
│ {null}    │
└───────────┘

So you can just set infer_schema_length to None pushing polars to scan full data to determine the schema:
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': ['{}', '{"b": "c"}', '{"e": "d"}']})

df.with_columns(
    pl.col('a').str.json_decode(infer_schema_length=None)
)

shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────┐
│ a           │
│ ---         │
│ struct[2]   │
╞═════════════╡
│ {null,null} │
│ {"c",null}  │
│ {null,"d"}  │
└─────────────┘


But the column has some filled strings of dicts also, with different key value pairs

@apostofes can you change your example to reflect that then? Solution might be different in this case

added example to it

@apostofes if you know your schema in advance then supllying dtype to json_decode() as shown above should work fine.

You'll need to specify the dtype argument of pl.Expr.str.json_decode correctly. Missing key-value pairs will be null.
In your example above, the dtype would be pl.Struct({"b": pl.String}). This works as expected for both provided dataframes.
df = pl.DataFrame({"meta_data": ["{}", '{"b": "c"}']})

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("meta_data").str.json_decode(dtype=pl.Struct({"b": pl.String}))
)

shape: (2, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ a         │
│ ---       │
│ struct[1] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {null}    │
│ {"c"}     │
└───────────┘

df = pl.DataFrame({"meta_data": ["{}"]})

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("meta_data").str.json_decode(dtype=pl.Struct({"b": pl.String}))
)

shape: (1, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ meta_data │
│ ---       │
│ struct[1] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {null}    │
└───────────┘

